# Let $X$ be a countably compact space such that every subspace of cardinality $\omega_1$ is metrizable. If $X$ is second countable, is $X$ metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

I am going through this paper:

Dow, A. An introduction to applications of elementary submodels to topology. Topology Proc. 13 (1988), https://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v13/tp13102.pdf

And I was stuck on the proof of
Theorem 3.1: If every subspace of cardinality $\omega_1$
of a countably compact space is metrizable, then the space
itself is metrizable.

The author first states a proposition:
Proposition 3.2 [J]. If every subspace of cardinality
at most $\omega_1$ has countable weight (weight of a topological space is the cardinality of the smallest base) then the space itself has
countable weight.

The proof starts off by assuming $X$ is not metrizable. Then the author goes on to claim "By
3.2, we know that $X$ has a subspace $Z$ with $|Z|= \omega_1$ and
$w(Z) > \omega$".

I don't quite follow how he got that conclusion. Does $X$ having weight $\omega$ make $X$ metrizable? Or does the properties that $X$ have imply that $X$ is Hausdorff? The author hasn't assumed any separation axioms for $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty much sure that Alan Dow follows the conventions in Engelking, General topology. Hence a countably compact space is Hausdorff by definition.

Then just to prove the claim is easy:
W.l.o.g. $|X| > \omega$. (Otherwise, $X$ would be compact, hence regular, hence metrizable.)
Assume there is no such $Z$. Then $w(X) = \omega$ by 3.2. In particular, X is first countable. Hence $X$ is regular (see, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379365/prove-that-a-countably-compact-first-countable-t-2-space-is-regular)). Hence $X$ is metrizable.

*Addendum:* If $|X| > \omega$ the above also holds without assuming that countably compact spaces are Hausdorff: See [here](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj20uHslNH7AhW6QvEDHYt8D3wQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS0166864109003563%2Fpdf%3Fmd5%3D1c7a389d402f050d4aa738c740761617%26pid%3D1-s2.0-S0166864109003563-main.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0hw1SkBCepDxZb_zUnhrn7), Lemma 1.1.

On the other hand, it is obviously false for the indiscrete topology on a countable space with at least two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here, compact and countably compact spaces are supposed Hausdorff.

If $X$ is countably compact and not metrizable then $X$ is not second countable, i.e.  $X$ has uncountable weight (hence by Proposition 3.2, it has a subspace $Z$ like claimed by the author).

This is because a countably compact and second countable space is compact, and a compact and second countable space is metrizable.